# Bend Rectangular Image into Square Image around Point [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 360 degree panoramic photo that I want transformed into a cube map.
In order to get the top and bottom faces, I cropped large rectangles from the top 25 percent of the photo and bottom 25% of the photo. The image below represents the bottom 25% of the 360 degree panoramic photo.

[image]

and I want to transform it into something *like* this

[image]

using HTML5 and Javascript.

The first image was cropped from a much larger one using this code

```
 imagePieces = [];
numColsToCut = 1;
var numRowsToCut = 1;
var widthOfOnePiece = image.width;
var heightOfOnePiece = image.height / 4;
var startHeight = 0;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = widthOfOnePiece;
        canvas.height = heightOfOnePiece;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log(image.height / 2);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, startHeight, widthOfOnePiece, heightOfOnePiece, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());
        document.getElementById('myImageElementInTheDom6').src = imagePieces[0];
```

Before placing the cropped image into the DOM element, I want to 'warp' it into the bottom image. Any tips? :)

Comment: But these aren't the same images...

Comment: @Purag just for visual aid purposes

Comment: Neither of these images is square. And one is upside-down.

Comment: This needs way more information.